# Place radio button's label next to the button

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following radio button in my view:

```
  <%= f.label :gender %>
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, true %> Male
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, false %> Female
```

The layout looks like this (each element is in a new row):

- radio button
- Male
- radio button
- Female

How do I make each of the above elements to appear next to each other, in the same row?

Comment: I think this may largely be dependent on the css framework you're using, IMHO

Comment: I'm using bootstrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @kumar mentioned, you should be able to do it this way:

```
<%= label_tag 'male', class: 'radio-inline' do %>
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, true %>
  Male
<% end %>

<%= label_tag 'female', class: 'radio-inline' do %>
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, false %>
  Female
<% end %>
```

You should also check out the `collection_radio_buttons`, I guess you should be able to use it for this too, *not totally sure of this though*:

```
<%= f.collection_radio_buttons :gender, [['male', true], ['female', false]], :last, :first %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
<%= label_tag 'male' do %>
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, true %>
  Male
<% end %>

<%= label_tag 'female' do %>
  <%= f.radio_button :gender, false %>
  Female
<% end %>
```

When you click on the text 'Male' or 'Female' the radio should be checked rather than clicking the radio itself. This will take care of that too.

Comment: Thanks! This causes the label to appear below the radio button. I want the label to be to the right of the button.